# Multiple VMs in the same Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-resource-manager, azure-resource-group

We have a single cloud service (within same resource group) in Azure that contains two VMs and would like each of the VMs to host some external facing websites on port 80.

Take for example:

```
VM1 = www.domain1.com:80, www.domain2.com:80
VM2 = www.domain3.com:80, www.domain4.com:80
```

It seems with Azure all resources within a Cloud Service share the same VIP, DNS Name and Endpoints settings and in particular the VIP is pointing to the cloud service and not any VM.  Since all the settings are shared we cannot create a DNS record pointing directly to the individual VMs.

Is this a limitation of Azure or setup issue?

We've tried giving each VM it's own Instance IP address  but only 1 can be assigned as we receive an error message on the 2nd VM:

Failed to update IP address in the virtual machine 'XXXX'. Error: The operation '08faed40bf2fad76a67fac50be475a33' failed: 'The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request.'

I did notice that the Virtual IP address assignment = Dynamic - But not sure if that's related to the above error?

Comment: How did you try to give the IP address?

Comment: Via the VM > Settings > IP Addresses blade - Then turn set: Instance IP Address = ON